# Making Multiple Sequential Network Request in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, combine

I need to make multiple request to the same url. For each request:

1. response is retrieved in the receiveValue closure
2. response which is a data is signed by invoking a webview which has javascript to sign the data. The webview view takes bindings as parameters
3. the signed data has to now be sent back to the server, that is another network request

However, in making these multiple requests, the next request should only be made after the previous request has completed, as the server will reject it if there is a request currently been processed. Below, I have tried to show some snippet of code what I have at the moment, but it is not working. Also, the webview view is in a .view file. In the View file, the completion closure assigns the data to `@state var` which triggers to webview view to sign the data. After which the signed data has to be sent to the server. I am new to this and any help will be well appreciated.

```
func makeMultiRequest(completion: @escaping (responseData: String) -> Void) {
        
        let url: String = URL ....
        
        let _: () = Just(url)
            .flatMap { url in
                Publishers.Sequence(sequence: Array(0..<3))
                    .flatMap { _ in
                        self.makeSingleRequest(url: url)
                            .flatMap { result -> AnyPublisher<SomeObject, Never> in
                                
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let response):
                                    return Just(response).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }, receiveValue: { dataToSign in
                completion(dataToSign)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    
    func makeSingleRequest(url: String) -> AnyPublisher<Result<SomeObject, Error>, Never> {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return ... some error
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        let request = createRequest()
        
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map(\.data)
            .tryMap { data -> SomeObject in
                return try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeObject.self, from: data)
            }
            .mapError { error in
                error as Error
            }
            .map { response -> Result<SomeObject, Error> in
                if response.error.isEmpty {
                    return Result.success(response)
                }
                // all other errors
                return Result.failure("Failed")
            }
            .catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Result<SomeObject, Error>, Never> in
                return Just(Result<SomeObject, Error>.failure(error))
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: Look into `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your `makeSingleRequest` function. You've got a lot going on in there and I'm not sure it's all necessary. A single request has a single result, either it succeeded or failed and every `Publisher` already has a mechanism for conveying that. You are also doing a lot of manual managing of the error conditions that seem unusual to me. I reworked the function and came up with something like this:

```
func makeSingleRequest(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<SomeObject, Error> {
      let request = URLRequest(url: url)
      return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: SomeObject.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note the use of the built in publisher operator `decode` which handles the JSON parsing for you so you don't have to do that explicitly.

To make a publisher that does three of them in a row:

```
/// create a publisher which makes three requests an sends the results of each to a subscriber
func makeMultiRequest(for urlString: String) throws -> AnyPublisher<SomeObject, Error> {
  guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    throw RequestErrors.invalidURLString(urlString)
  }

  return (0..<3)
    .publisher
    .map { _ in return url }
    .flatMap(makeSingleRequest)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note that a sequence, like the range `(0..<3)` already has a `publisher` method. The `flatMap` is what runs the pipeline create by `makeSingleRequest` and extracts the `SomeObject` instance that is generated then passes it further down the pipeline.

And you can call it as:

```
let subscription = try makeMultiRequest(for: "http://someserver.com")
  .sink { completion in
    switch completion {
    case .finished:
      // all done
      break
    case .failure(let error):
      // Do something with an error
      break
    }
  } receiveValue: { someObject in
    // do a thing with the object
  }
```

The `receiveValue` should be called three times as each request completes.